# Tor relay and web server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: relays, raspberry-pi, web-proxy

I have web server on my Raspberry Pi. After I installed and started to use Tor Relay with this [manual](http://unsuspectingbit.com/tutorial-private-anonymizing-proxy-raspberry-pi-tor-based/), I am not able to connect through proxy to my Raspberry Pi web server.  To run Tor proxy on unsupported device I use lighttpd. In the installation process it is written that it can't be used because port 80 is used with other service. I changed port 80 in the setting to port 8080 and it solved this problem.  Please tell me how to open access to Raspberry Pi web server. Despite my best effort, with my current abilities I am not able to access it. Would somebody help me with this problem please?

Comment: So after switching to port 8080 can you access your web-server?

Comment: Do you want your web server available over the clearnet at all, or just as a Tor hidden service?

Comment: An aside, but you might get better mileage with a BeagleBone Black. * http://datko.net/2014/05/13/bbb_torrc/
* https://vincetocco.com/beaglebone-black-as-a-cheap-tor-router-proxy-with-google-chrome/ Datko did some comparisons with RaspberryPi vs BeagleBone and was able to get >3x faster speeds with the BeagleBone (forget the exact increase, it was between 3-10x).

Answer (score 2):

Internet traffic (HTTP) is transmitted via port 80. Tor and Apache (or another web server) do not share ports well, because of problems with intercepting each others traffic, etc. You can either change the port of your web server, which I don't recommend, or change the port of Tor.